# Random numbers associated in Monte Carlo Simulation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, monte-carlo

An Outcome has a probability of 35% of occurring. To Simulate this outcome, which integer random numbers on a scale of 0-99 should be associated with it for Monte Carlo Simulation?

Comment: Are the numbers uniformly distributed?

Comment: Nothing specific was mentioned in the question.

Comment: There are 100 possible outcomes, so you need "success" in exactly 35 of them, i.e., $0 \to 34$ inclusive.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork 65-99 was also in options. Can you explain why 0-34 and not 65-99?

Comment: Of course you can choose *any* set of exactly 35 distinct integers.  Of course.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Should the 35 distinct number be continuous? I had following options, out of which only one is correct,
0-34
0-35
65-99
any set of distinct 35 numbers
none of these
which one do you think is the answer?

Comment: Makes no difference, since each selection is independent.